# NotSerializableException while saving fragment state

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm occasionally seeing exceptions that I do not really understand. Here's what I do: I have an interface

```
public interface IResultProcessor<T> extends Serializable {

    void processResult(T result);

}
```

, instances of which I use in this class:

```
public class ConfirmationDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public static void executeAfterConfirmation(FragmentActivity activity, IResultProcessor<Void> runnable,
        String title, String message, int icon, String positiveButtonText, String negativeButtonText) {

        ConfirmationDialogFragment fragment = new ConfirmationDialogFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable(ARG_RUNNABLE, runnable);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        fragment.show(activity.getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");
    }

}
```

In the `onCreateDialog()` method, I receive the `IProcessResult` instance and execute it if the user has confirmed.

I then use all this in an activity as follows:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial") 
IResultProcessor<Void> processor = new IResultProcessor<Void>() {

    @Override
    public void processResult(Void result) {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                DBFacade.INSTANCE.saveSession(session);
                return "My msg...";
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }.execute((Void) null);
    }
};
ConfirmationDialogFragment.executeAfterConfirmation(this, processor, "Save session?", "dialog text", R.drawable.ic_dialog_info, "Save", "Don't save");
```

The `session` object saved in the `AsyncTask` does not implement `Serializable` (but `Parcelable` because of other reasons) and is a field of MyActivity.

And here's the exception I'm seeing:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = MyActivity$3)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1279)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1233)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:591)
    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1619)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:605)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentState.writeToParcel(Fragment.java:132)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedArray(Parcel.java:1102)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerState.writeToParcel(FragmentManager.java:357)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1254)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1173)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:591)
    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1619)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:605)
    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:2078)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:2874)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: MyActivity
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1364)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1671)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:979)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:368)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1074)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1404)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1671)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1274)
    ... 23 more
java.io.NotSerializableException: MyActivity
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1364)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1671)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:979)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:368)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1074)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1404)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1671)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1274)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1233)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:591)
    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1619)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:605)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentState.writeToParcel(Fragment.java:132)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedArray(Parcel.java:1102)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerState.writeToParcel(FragmentManager.java:357)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1254)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1173)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:591)
    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1619)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:605)
    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:2078)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:2874)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: Do you have an inner class in MyActivity that is not serializable?

Comment: @ChuckNorris No... I have an inner class which inherits from BroadCastReceiver, but implements Serializable. I'm also using an anonymous inner class (used in a different method than the one which contains the above code) which indeed is not serializable, but that shouldn't matter!? The class MyActivity itself doesn't implement Serializable, it just inherits from android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity. Does it have to be serializable?

Comment: There is a caused by ... NotSerializableException: MyActivity. Usually this means that it does not implement Serializable: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/NotSerializableException.html

Comment: @ChuckNorris In MyActivity I'm holding references to some Fragments, a TextToSpeech instance, a Vibrator instance, and some custom classes which are also not serializable. These fields are initialized during the onCreate() and onAttachFragment methods. My understanding is that it wouldn't make sense to initialize these fields using the classes' default constructor (as the doc of Serializable says) - in other words, if MyActivity itself needs to be serialized, than this is the actual issue. Do you agree? If you don't, I will look deeper into this...

Comment: Yeah, if something is being serialized, it expects it as well as all instance variables to be serializable or transient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't totally understood, but apparently solved the issue. The exceptions were thrown when the activity was destroyed because another one came into the foreground. I solved it by converting the anonymous IResultProcessor class into a static inner class of my activity.

Comment: Still not understand  why happen when  activity was destroyed