# Application crashes when home button press

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity, fragment-tab-host

hi frnds am developing an application which load a fragmentActivity. the fragment activity contains tabhost with 4 tabs, each tab load fragments. the application works smoothily when i run the application but, when we **press the home button** or any other apps runs then my **application crashes...**.

this is my log cat

```
09-12 05:47:39.055: E/AndroidRuntime(3692): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-12 05:47:39.055: E/AndroidRuntime(3692): java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value WelcomeFragment{40d3ae00}
09-12 05:47:39.055: E/AndroidRuntime(3692):     at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1235)
09-12 05:47:39.055: E/AndroidRuntime(3692):     at android.os.Parcel.writeList(Parcel.java:622)
09-12 05:47:39.055: E/AndroidRuntime(3692):     at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1195)
09-12 05:47:39.055: E/AndroidRuntime(3692):     at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:591)
09-12 05:47:39.055: E/AndroidRuntime(3692):     at android.os.Parcel.writeMap(Parcel.java:575)
09-12 05:47:39.055: E/AndroidRuntime(3692):     at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1166)
09-12 05:47:39.055: E/AndroidRuntime(3692):     at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:591)
09-12 05:47:39.055: E/AndroidRuntime(3692):     at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1627)
09-12 05:47:39.055: E/AndroidRuntime(3692):     at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:605)
09-12 05:47:39.055: E/AndroidRuntime(3692):     at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:2252)
09-12 05:47:39.055: E/AndroidRuntime(3692):     at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3052)
09-12 05:47:39.055: E/AndroidRuntime(3692):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
09-12 05:47:39.055: E/AndroidRuntime(3692):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-12 05:47:39.055: E/AndroidRuntime(3692):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-12 05:47:39.055: E/AndroidRuntime(3692):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
09-12 05:47:39.055: E/AndroidRuntime(3692):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-12 05:47:39.055: E/AndroidRuntime(3692):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-12 05:47:39.055: E/AndroidRuntime(3692):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
09-12 05:47:39.055: E/AndroidRuntime(3692):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
09-12 05:47:39.055: E/AndroidRuntime(3692):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and this is my tabActivity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        View absView=LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.abs_layout, null);
        actionBar.setCustomView(absView);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab_layout);
        tabHost =(TabHost) findViewById(R.id.myTabHost);
        tabHost.setup();

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            initializeTabHost();
            tabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(savedInstanceState.getString("tab"));
            backStacks=(HashMap<String, Stack<Fragment>>) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("stacks");
        }
        else
        {
            backStacks = new HashMap<String, Stack<Fragment>>();
            for(int i=0;i<stackKey.length;i++)
                backStacks.put(stackKey[i], new Stack<Fragment>());
            initializeTabHost();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
//      super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putString("tab", tabHost.getCurrentTabTag());
        outState.putSerializable("stacks", backStacks);
    }
    private void initializeTabHost() {
        tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
        addTab(this, stackKey[0], labels[0],WelcomeFragment.class,R.drawable.menu_home);
        addTab(this, stackKey[1], labels[1], ShopListFragment.class, R.drawable.menu_shops);
        addTab(this, stackKey[2], labels[2], MyDealsFragment.class, R.drawable.menu_mydeals);
        addTab(this, stackKey[3], labels[3], MyProfileFragment.class, R.drawable.menu_profile);
        addTab(this, stackKey[4], labels[4], SettingFragment.class, R.drawable.menu_settings_on);
    }
    private void addTab(TabActivity activity,String tag,int label,Class<?> class1, int image)
    {
        Stack<Fragment> backStack = backStacks.get(tag);
        View tabView=createTabView(label, image);
        TabSpec tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(tag).setIndicator(tabView).setContent(activity.new TabFactory(activity));
        Fragment fragment = (Fragment) Fragment.instantiate(activity, class1.getName(),null);
        if(backStack.isEmpty())
            if(fragment!=null)
                backStack.push(fragment);
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

    }
```

and this is my WelcomeFragment

```
public class WelcomeFragment extends Fragment
{
     ViewPageAdapter mAdapter;
        ViewPager mPager;
        CirclePageIndicator mIndicator;
        List<Fragment> fragments;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_welcome_layout,null);
        mPager=(ViewPager)view.findViewById(R.id.myViewPager);
        mIndicator=(CirclePageIndicator)view.findViewById(R.id.circlePageIndicator1);
        mAdapter = new ViewPageAdapter(getActivity());
        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);
        return view;
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

Comment: Post java your java class for this exception

Comment: see this questionhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/13156727/notserializableexception-while-saving-fragment-state

Comment: A `HashMap` implements **Serializable** not **java.io.Serializable**. Android is expecting `java.io.Serializable`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13207376/is-hashtable-hashmap-serializable-in-java